# How to read regex in my Email Validation

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I found a solution with regex how to validate an email.
But i don't really understand how to read it properly since this is the first time i'm using regex.
Can anybody explain me how to read it in Words? Cause creating this with if statements would be pain in the ass.

My code:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text))
{
    label8.Text = "E-pasts netika ievadīts!";
}
else
{
    Regex emailExpression = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]{2,28}[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$");
    if (emailExpression.IsMatch(textBox4.Text))
    {
        label8.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        label8.Text = "E-pasts ievadīts nepareizi!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I can recommend Lea Verou's talk on regex. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkluES9Rvak

Answer (score 0):

For regex follow the link :http://www.regexr.com/

There paste your regex expression `[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]{2,28}[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]`

Hover over the each text and you will get their meaning

A few example:

`a-z` will match character in range between a and z

`A-Z` will match character in range between A-Z

`\w` matches any word character

`{2,28}` match between 2 and 28 of preceeding token

Answer (score 0):

Here is the breakdown. Just note all `[ ]` are a **set** of single items(s) the following can be either a `*` (zero or more) a `+` one or more or `{ , }` (min and max) occurrences.

If one comments the pattern to show *an inherent pattern*, it is actually easier to understand, once tabbed over at key points; and I will do that:

```
var pattern = @"
^                  # Beginning of line, data must start here instead of matching any location *away from the start*.
      [a-zA-Z]         # A set of characters from a-z and A-Z but just one
      [\w\.-]{2,28}    # A set of any word character \w=a-zA-Z0-9 with a literal period and dash; but minimum of 2 to a max of 28 characters. 
      [a-zA-Z0-9]      # Could be replaced with a single \w; this ensure that there is a character and not a non character before the @
  @                # Literal `@`
      [a-zA-Z0-9]      # same as \w; ensures a character
      [\w\.-]*         # '*' = Zero or more of the set with a literal period in the set.
      [a-zA-Z0-9]      # same as \w; ensures a character
 \.                # Literal Period must be matched.
      [a-zA-Z]         # A set of characters from a-z and A-Z but just one
      [a-zA-Z\.]*      # zero or more characters with a literal period `.`.
      [a-zA-Z]         # same as \w; ensures a character
$                  # End; contrains the whole match with the `^` so no loose characters are left out of the match
";

// IgnorePatternWhitespace allows us to comment the pattern; does not affect processing in any way.
Regex.IsMatch("abcd@def.com", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace); // True/Valid
Regex.IsMatch("1abcd@def.com", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);// False/Invalid
Regex.IsMatch("abc@def.com", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);  // False/Invalid
```

---

Note there is a logic flaw in the pattern as found in test #3. For `abc@def.com` would fail because the pattern looks for a minimum of 2 characters between the first character and the last character prefix before the `@`. I would change it to a `*` instead which means zero or more.